# Pun/Joke way of saying "Happy Belated Birthday"

Tags: jokes

My friend's birthday was yesterday. Is there any **interesting** way to say 
"Happy Belated Birthday" such as 御誕生昨日,　御誕生先日,　御誕生前日

Will it translate or will it just seem strange?

Note: I am not trying to just say "sorry I forgot your birthday, happy belated birthday". Rather I'm trying to be cute with language play

In English I can make any numbrer of dumb jokes any pretty much anyone fluent in English will get it.

- Happy Day After your Birthday!
- Happy Un-Birthday! (reference to Alice in Wonderland).
- Happy Birth(Yester)day!
- Happy 3 days after 2 days before your Birthday

They might not be funny haha but pretty much any one fluent in English would get what is trying to be said and get that message and intention.

Is there a way to say something similar in Japanese?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 御誕生昨日,　御誕生先日,　御誕生前日
>   Will it translate or will it just seem strange?

These won't make much sense, and I don't think they'd look/sound really interesting or funny, I'm afraid.

As you might already know, we usually say "Happy Belated Birthday" as 「遅くなったけど、お誕生日おめでとう」「遅れてしまったけど、お誕生日おめでとう」 or maybe 「過ぎちゃったけど、お誕生日おめでとう」 etc.

I think you could jokingly say to friends something like...

> 「お誕生日の次の日おめでとう。」
>   「お誕生日プラス１日おめでとう。」

Comment: Maybe too late, but, while I'm in no position to comment Chocolate's Japanese, I think the conclusion is that an apology works a lot better. Telling a joke, which the person immediately understands was not come up by you, and was just made to undermine the fact that you forgot his/her birthday, brings an outcome far below that of apologizing in a way that makes the person know that you made some efforts to find out how to sincerely apologize, in a way he/she knows you could not do without really having put in some efforts. ) How to do it, then is up to those more talented on this site to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest one for a joke:

> 今日もお誕生日おめでとう

You can think of it as "Happy Birthday to you, today as well."

It may elicit an unhappy and maybe angry response, the kind that might only be safe to fool around with friends with. At the very least you'll get a 何それ、意味分かんない